# Document not saved after importing content

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop, windows-server-2012

I'm using **Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word** for importing document content from another file. It's working fine in console application but having problem in server. Document wouldn't changes after importing file document.

```
string templatePath = /*path template*/;
string contentPath = /*path content*/;
var app = new Word.Application();
var tempDoc = app.Documents.Open(templatePath);
tempDoc.Activate();
tempDoc.Content.Find.ClearFormatting();

int index = tempDoc.Content.Text.LastIndexOf("[content]");
int lastIndex = index + 9;
var rng = tempDoc.Range(index, lastIndex);
rng.Select();
rng.Cut();
rng.InsertFile(contentPath);
tempDoc.Close();
app.Quit();
```

I have not found any error. Anyone can help me, Why template Document not changes?

Comment: Are you missing a save operation?

Comment: @MarkusDeibel Trying with save operation. Same thing was heppening

Comment: Automating Microsoft Office applications in a server environment is not supported: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office I recommend you leverage the Open XML file format (using the Open XML SDK, for example) for editing Word document content in a server environment. That kind of solution does not even require Word to be installed on the server, and it executes much faster.